# Что такое float и double?

Tags: c#, математика, информатика

Изучаю C# по книге Шилдта, где он коротко описал эти типы, мне же описания не хватило в силу того, что в школе информатику не трогали. Где можно узнать больше о понятиях точности, разряда, этого раздела в целом и соответствующих функциях, желательно начиная с фундаментальных вещей, поскольку я в этом новичок.

Comment: Начать можно например отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Помню, сдавал вступительный по математике. Сосед спереди пристал - скажи ответ в задаче, да скажи ответ. Я сказал: "1,6". Он смотрит. Я: "Что смотришь?" - "А как это написать?"

Comment: Я просто прошу дать некоторую литературу, где об этом моменте можно узнать подробнее

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы знаете, что числа бывают разные: натуральные, целые, рациональные(дроби) и т.д. Наиболее естественны, для "компьютера", целые (и в двоичном представлении :) ), а все другие приходится представлять в виде набора целых. Очень упрощенно, можно сказать, что существует несколько подходов к таком представлению рациональных чисел:

- в лоб, хранить два целых числа, числитель и знаменатель. Обычно такой способ не используется, так как имеет такие недостатки, как нестабильная точность (и абсолютная и относительная), а так же неоднозначность представления (и интерпретации) такого числа, например 1/2 и 4/8 - мы должны интерпретировать как одно число или как два разных
- [с фиксированной точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9), мы используем одно целое число, просто "держа в уме", что часть значимых цифр представляют "дробную часть". Обычно такие типы называются `decimal` или `money`. Достоинством таких типов является стабильная *абсолютная* точность и скорость операций с ними. Недостатком является, обычно, довольно узкий диапазон представляемых значений, тем более узкий чем больше необходимая точность. Применяются, чаще всего, для представления денежных сумм, временных периодов и т.д.
- [с плавающей точкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9), можно представить число в виде "двух" разных целых: мантисы и порядка. Это и есть те самые типы `float` и `double` :) Такие числа имеют более стабильную *относительную* точность, но не абсолютную. Большим достоинством таких чисел, является очень широкий диапазон представляемых значений.

Если же вам надо, более подробно, диапозоны значений, конкретный способ представления, количество необходимых бит и т.д. , то нужно копаться в спецификациях компилятора, а возможно и процессора.

Comment: На всякий... Текст в одном месте чуть неоднозначный. Можно прочитать так, что ```float``` это мантисса,  а ```double```  - порядок. Но и  ```float``` и ```double``` - типы с плавающей точкой (или плавающей запятой), имеющие разный диапазон значений.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов , редактура, всего ответа действительно не помешает :( , но не знаю, имеет ли смысл, делать ее для закрытого вопроса

Comment: не знаю. Но иногда нахожу полезную информацию в ответах и комментариях к закрытым вопросам :)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо. Почитал дополнительно "Код" Петцольда, там об этом говорилось, причину понял

Answer (score 0):

Относится к value types. Также считается Floating-point numeric types:

```
float   ±1.5 x 10−45 to ±3.4 x 1038 ~6-9 цифр   4 bytes
double  ±5.0 × 10−324 to ±1.7 × 10308   ~15-17 цифр 8 bytes
```